# Economic Indices related to Food

Tags: data-request

I'm interested in knowing about some of the available economic indices relating to food. I know the CPI has a food component but are there any others? Espically those who are commonly reported by international organizations like the World Bank or IMF.
I'm interested in looking at whether the Russian/Ukraine crisis has had an impact like many claim it would on Subsaharan Africa food security.
Any ideas of publically available indices I could look at. I'd also be happy to know about indices I could potentially combine.

(If this is the wrong section to post this, I'd be happy to move it somewhere else)